# PHP CURL transfer file: 55, Send failure: Connection was reset

Tags: php, curl

My code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://site/index.php?1c.upload&filename=' . $filename);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $files); //Array CURLFile
    echo $out = curl_exec($curl);
```

When I try send file 10Mb - all correctly.
When I try send file ~200Mb - I get error

> 55, Send failure: Connection was reset

or

> 56, Recv failure: Connection was reset

I'm try write `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Expect:']);`
Not result...
And try`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3600);` - same...

In php.ini:

```
max_execution_time = 3600
max_input_time = 3600
upload_max_filesize = 500M
post_max_size = 500M
```

Same try `set_time_limit(3600);` in php file... but not result...

Return array:

```
[url] => myurl
[content_type] =>
[http_code] => 0
[header_size] => 0
[request_size] => 306
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 29.328
[namelookup_time] => 0.016
[connect_time] => 0.031
[pretransfer_time] => 0.031
[size_upload] => 116490450
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 3971987
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => 175979724
[starttransfer_time] => 1.045
[redirect_time] => 0
[redirect_url] =>
[primary_ip] => serverIP
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_port] => 80
[local_ip] => 192.168.0.45
[local_port] => 1854
```

Comment: You got connection problem while uploading a file. It happens a lot when under a poor internet connection.

Comment: I dont think...

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved!
Need change Nginx config:

```
client_max_body_size
```